# Need to upload stats data from a csv file to sql database automatically every day?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Ok so im trying to use phpjobscheduler to update stats every day, It runs a command every day to open the php page and updates the db.
I have Googled and this is the code I managed so far:

```
<?php
$mysqli  =  new mysqli('localhost','xxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx');
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'xxxxx.CSV' REPLACE INTO TABLE `Stats_Day` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@txdate, department, code, descript, QTY, Total) SET  txdate = STR_TO_DATE(@txdate, '%Y/%m/%d')";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($mysqli->error) {
    try {   
        throw new Exception("MySQL error $mysqli->error <br> Query:<br> $query", $msqli->errno);   
    } catch(Exception $e ) {
        echo "Error No: ".$e->getCode(). " - ". $e->getMessage() . "<br >";
        echo nl2br($e->getTraceAsString());
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

This however is not working it gives me a blank page,
and nothing is updated on the SQL-database?
it connects to the db 
 (enter wrong details it shows incorrect user details)

but is not updating the db ? and shows no errors?

Please assist?
all I need to do is to update the db with the data from the .csv file every day at 1am.

Comment: You need to take a closer look at your $query and check the ' and " .

Comment: please check the quotes in your query, they seem to be wrong. Can you set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and check which error is displayed ?

Comment: If i just have the login detail incorrect and remove the $query I get a error :<code>Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user</code><br/> If I add the $query with incorrect login details it shows only the blank page?

Comment: ok I got it the error code im getting is</br>12 Notice: mysqli::query(): send of 2 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe</br> line 12 Warning: mysqli::query(): HTTP request failed, unexpected end of socket!</br>line 12 Notice: Undefined variable: con</br>on line 22 Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quote at `ENCLOSED BY` part. Without that, you terminated your string.

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'xxxxx.CSV' REPLACE INTO TABLE `Stats_Day` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@txdate, department, code, descript, QTY, Total) SET  txdate = STR_TO_DATE(@txdate, '%Y/%m/%d')";
```

**Note**

- Use `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to cactch your errors while developing.

Comment: it should actually look like this but it still is not working?:             FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES

Comment: In this code, what you commented here, the double quotes not escaped yet. Use this: ENCLOSED BY `'\"'`

Comment: ok so this is my error:  <code>Notice: mysqli::query(): send of 25 bytes failed with errno=104 Connection reset by peer in /home/sites/xxx.co.za/public_html/stats/phpjobscheduler/Stats_Day.php on line 13 Notice: mysqli::query(): send of 2 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in /home/sites/xxx.co.za/public_html/stats/phpjobscheduler/Stats_Day.php on line 13 Warning: mysqli::query(): HTTP request failed, unexpected end of socket! in /home/sites/xxx.co.za/public_html/stats/phpjobscheduler/Stats_Day.php on line 13</code> this is from row 13

Comment: <code>FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' IGNORE 1 LINES (@txdate, department, code, descript, QTY, Total) SET  txdate = STR_TO_DATE(@txdate, '%Y/%m/%d')";</code>

Comment: the rest of the errors fixed just this the maxed allowed packs on the db is : max_allowed_packet  67108864 and should be more than what I need.?